# How to create BitMap Images using different colors in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to develop a Desktop application using VC++ and MFC I'm new to it.
Please help me..

Comment: Refer [this post](http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=Visual_C_PlusPlus&seqNum=71) it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a library like CxImage (http://www.xdp.it/cximage.htm) to do all the heavy lifting of bitmap creation/loading/manipulation.  I've used it in a number of projects and it's saved my life quite a few times!